# jQuery Sortable: disable reception of new items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists that are controlled by the jQuery UI widget Sortable.

One list is intended to supply values for another.  The receiving list is supposed to have a hard limit of 10 items.

Now, I can implement an event listener that keeps count of the list elements and disables the reception list when the limit is hit.  However, this also disables the removal of elements.

Is there a way to block the drop into a sortable list while still allowing drag outs?

```
List 1 < -- Elements swapped between -- > List 2

List 1 now contains 10 elements, is disabled to drag and drop.
How can list 1's drop event be blocked while allowing drag?
```

Comment: You can set the [accept option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept) on List 1 to a function that disallows elements from List 2 when there are already 10 elements in List 1. Note that a jQuery sortable has all the properties of a draggable/droppable as well.

Comment: How can I access those droppable properties, though?  There is nothing explicit in the API docs, and I've been using the `sortreceive` and `sortremove` events for a listener.  There's no explicit way to do that in the docs.

Comment: You access them just as you would other properties - through the `sortable` function. On the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) it says "By default, sortable items share draggable properties."